# Kubernetes dashboard and ingress controller doesn’t work, in local minikube

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

Ingress controller

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dashboard-ingress
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
spec:
  rules:
  - host: dashboard.info
    http:
      paths:
        - pathType: Prefix
          path: "/"
          backend:
            service:
              name: kubernetes-dashboard
              port:
                number: 80
```

`kubectl get service -n kubernetes-dashboard` returns
[image]

`kubectl get ingresses -n=kubernetes-dashboard` returns

[image]

`kubectl get all -n ingress-Nginx`
[image]
I have the IP in my hosts

`192.168.49.2 dashboard.info`

I am new to learning kubernetes, so I followed this documentation
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/
but I am not sure what is wrong with my setup.

Comment: Did you run `minikube` on your teminal? What do you see when you run `minikube dashboard`?

Comment: I runed `minikube start`  . 
Besides that, my `minikube dashboard` command opens the dashboard but uses a different IP address.
`http://127.0.0.1:54879/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/`

Comment: `127.0.0.1` is your localhost, that is correct. You can run `minikube ip` to find your container's IP, that is 192.168.49.2, as you see now.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/zxE0OdS.png Don't you see this dashboard ?

Comment: I tried to use the 192.168.49.2, but it doesn’t show anything. The page doesn’t work—the same as dashboard.info.
I saw your showed dashboard using command` minikube dashboard` it opens in the localhost

Comment: I suppose this IP 192.168.49.2 is for external usage, right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct

Comment: @NairiAbgaryan, what is the error that you get when accessing the dashboard?

Comment: @SahanGunathilaka The error

This page isn’t working 
dashboard.com didn’t send any data.

Comment: There is no issue with provided issues in the description. Are you sure that you are accessing the correct domain? Because you have added dashboard.info as the host in the ingress resource. There is no dashboard.com involvement here. Please check your hosts file mappings for the correct domain.